# Bug in datatable with caption and fixedRownames

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I am trying to build datatable with fixedheader, fixed rownames, and a title.
That's the code i am using:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)


ui <- basicPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  m = as.data.frame(round(matrix(rnorm(10000), 20), 5))
  data<-datatable(
    m, extensions =  c('FixedColumns',"FixedHeader"),
    caption ='long title',
    options = list(
      scrollX = TRUE, scrollY = 300,
      paging=F,
      fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 1)
    ))
  
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When running the code you can see that the title is forcing the first column to take a new line.
I tried using this code:

```
 caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
      style = 'caption-side: top; text-align: center;',   
      'long title'
    )
```

It worked when the caption-side was set to bottom but not top

Any idea how i can keep the caption-side:top and make it work

Appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but...

The problem is caused by `fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 1)`.  Comment it out, and the table displays correctly.  Also, I notice that "long title" appears in the header as soon as the table displays.  "title", immediately below, appears only when the table is populated.  That may be causing the undesirable offset.

`FixedColumns` seems to be a problematic `DT` extension.  See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) for example.

I understand why you want the fixed column.  The bug appears to be in the extension rather than in `DT` itself.  Sorry I can't be of more help.